# Is there a way to loop through an HTML quiz to get text from "laber for" with value "true"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a multiple choice radio button quiz. I want to get all the correct answers and print them. Correct answers are marked value="true" in html. Other answers have different value. How can I loop through to get text of all the correct answers from  using javascript or PHP? Example:

```html
<span class='mlw_qmn_question_number'>1. </span>
<span class='mlw_qmn_question '>Roberta _____ from Canada.</span>
<div class='qmn_radio_answers mlwRequiredRadio'>

  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-are'>
    <input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_1' value='are' />
    <label for='question21_1'>are</label>
  </div>

  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-is'>
    <input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_2' value='true' />
    <label for='question21_2'>is</label>
  </div>

  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-am'>
    <input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_3' value='am' />
    <label for='question21_3'>am</label>
  </div>

  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-be'>
    <input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_4' value='be' />
    <label for='question21_4'>be</label>
  </div>

  <input type='radio' style='display: none;' name='question21' id='question21_none' checked='checked' value='No Answer Provided' />
</div>
```

Comment: In JavaScript with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). First find all the inputs with `querySelectorAll`. Then use `map` with `querySelector` to find the corresponding label for each input and create an array of labels. Then map the labels to its content.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[value=true]');
const labels = Array.prototype.map.call(inputs, input => document.querySelector(`label[for=${input.id}]`));

console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(labels, label => label.innerHTML));
```

```html
<span class='mlw_qmn_question_number'>1. </span><span class='mlw_qmn_question '>Roberta _____ from Canada.</span>
<div class='qmn_radio_answers mlwRequiredRadio'>
  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-are'><input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_1' value='are' /> <label for='question21_1'>are</label></div>
  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-is'><input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_2' value='true' /> <label for='question21_2'>is</label></div>
  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-am'><input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_3' value='am' /> <label for='question21_3'>am</label></div>
  <div class='qmn_mc_answer_wrap' id='question21-be'><input type='radio' class='qmn_quiz_radio' name='question21' id='question21_4' value='be' /> <label for='question21_4'>be</label></div><input type='radio' style='display: none;' name='question21' id='question21_none' checked='checked' value='No Answer Provided' />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it was very helpful. I got all the correct answer printed. I think my question should be posted. Why it was marked as not clear?